# How can i recognize changed values in a schema-trigger?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

can someone tell me how to find some differences between new and old values in a schema-trigger? 
The Trigger runs on `INSERT`,`UPDATE`,`DELETE`. I know that trgigger can use `:old.*` and `:new.*`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you mean that you have a row-level trigger, not a schema-level trigger.  A schema-level trigger fires when, for example, someone does DDL on a table in the schema.  It doesn't make sense to talk about new and old values when you're talking about a schema-level trigger.

And if we're talking about row-level triggers, I assume that you're only really interested in `UPDATE` statements.  If you are inserting or deleting data, you're naturally changing every column in the table.

So, if we are discussing row-level triggers that fire on `UPDATE`, you can potentially use the `UPDATING` function.  That tells you whether a particular column is being updated.  It does not, however, necessarily tell you that the data is being changed.  The statement

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET col1 = col1;
```

updates `COL1` for every row in `TABLE_NAME` but does not actually change any data.  If that is acceptable, you can do something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_table_name
  BEFORE UPDATE ON table_name
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF( updating( 'COL1' ) )
  THEN
    <<col1 was updated>>
  END IF;

  IF( updating( 'COL2' ) )
  THEN
    <<col2 was updated>>
  END IF;

  ...
END;
```

You could make that a bit more dynamic by just looping over the data in `USER_TAB_COLS`, i.e.

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create table foo (
  2    col1 number,
  3    col2 number,
  4    col3 number
  5* )
SQL> /

Table created.

SQL> create trigger trg_foo
  2    before update on foo
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    for cols in (select *
  6                   from user_tab_cols
  7                  where table_name = 'FOO')
  8    loop
  9      if updating( cols.column_name )
 10      then
 11        dbms_output.put_line( 'Updated ' || cols.column_name );
 12      end if;
 13    end loop;
 14  end;
 15  /

Trigger created.

SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> insert into foo values( 1, 2, 3 );

1 row created.

SQL> update foo
  2     set col2 = col2 + 1,
  3         col3 = col3 * 2;
Updated COL2
Updated COL3

1 row updated.
```

While this can show you all the columns that are being updated, however, the major downside is that there is no way to access the `:new` and `:old` values in a similar dynamic fashion.  So you can find out that `COL2` was updated but you can't determine what the `:new.col2` or `:old.col2` value was without statically referring to those values.

Potentially, depending on the problem you're trying to solve, you could write code that dynamically generated your trigger by looking at the data in the data dictinoary.  Something along the lines of this block will generate a trigger for a particular table that prints out all the `:new` values

```
DECLARE
  l_tbl_name VARCHAR2(100) := 'FOO';
  l_sql_stmt VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  l_sql_stmt := 'CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_' || l_tbl_name ||
                '  BEFORE UPDATE ON ' || l_tbl_name ||
                '  FOR EACH ROW ' || 
                'BEGIN ';
  FOR cols IN (SELECT *
                 FROM user_tab_cols
                WHERE table_name = l_tbl_name )
  LOOP
    l_sql_stmt := l_sql_stmt ||
                  ' IF UPDATING( ''' || cols.column_name || ''' ) ' ||
                  ' THEN ' ||
                  '   dbms_output.put_line( :new.' || cols.column_name || '); ' ||
                  ' END IF; ';
  END LOOP;
  l_sql_stmt := l_sql_stmt || ' END; ';
  dbms_output.put_line( l_sql_stmt );
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_stmt;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
          :old            :new
=======================================================
insert | null         |    new value to be inserted
update | old value    |    new value to be updated
delete | old value    |    null
=======================================================
```

The above values are referred with reference to row level triggers,which means that triggered is fired each time for each row .

The above  table shows  value of new old with respect to the above dml statements ,lets take an example.

```
Insert into abc (1,'gaurav soni',pune);--empid,name,city
```

Suppose i have a trigger on table abc that when inserting into table abc ,check whether the city is present in location table or not (i know we can do this with foreign key constraint ) but this is an example ,so we can refer city as `:new.city` ,but we cannot refer `:old .city` in case of inserting because its value is `null`.

In case of `update` we can refer both the `:new and :old value`

In case of `delete` we can refer only the `old value` as the `new value` is `null` in case of `deleting`.

**Note**:using of `:new` in case of `delete` ,`:old` in case of `inserting` will not give you `compile time error` ,but surely it will boom  and give you `run time error`
You can use `INSERTING,DELETING` clause to avoid this .

Comment: Thank you, but is the only way that i compare each column? I search a function which give me the changed columns

Comment: @destiny:I am not getting what you are looking for ,please elaborate your answer ,may be the answer given by Justin helps you !,but he also worked in assumption ,please elaborate so that other might understand what you are looking for .